# MySQL Query for Distinct and SUM Value

Tags: mysql

I Have Database like this

```
ID      DATE        QTY  PRICE
1   05-02-13 00:45  70  0
1   05-02-13 00:45  25  20000
1   05-02-13 00:45  3   1750000
1   05-02-13 00:45  50  0
1   05-02-13 00:45  5   0
1   05-02-13 00:45  200 0
1   05-02-13 00:45  15000   8500
8   11-02-13 16:27  150 17000
8   11-02-13 16:27  150 2000
9   11-02-13 21:40  1   7500000
9   11-02-13 21:40  1   15000000
1   15-02-13 15:15  70  0
1   15-02-13 15:15  25  20000
1   15-02-13 15:15  3   1750000
1   15-02-13 15:15  50  0
1   15-02-13 15:15  5   0
1   15-02-13 15:15  200 0
1   15-02-13 15:15  15000   8500
```

And I need Query in MySQL to show data only like this:

```
ID     DATE         QTY  PRICE
8   11-02-13 16:27  150 17000
8   11-02-13 16:27  150 2000
9   11-02-13 21:40  1   7500000
9   11-02-13 21:40  1   15000000
1   15-02-13 15:15  70  0
1   15-02-13 15:15  25  20000
1   15-02-13 15:15  3   1750000
1   15-02-13 15:15  50  0
1   15-02-13 15:15  5   0
1   15-02-13 15:15  200 0
1   15-02-13 15:15  15000   8500
```

So I can SUM QTY * PRICE

Its only User Newest ID and sum QTY * PRICE

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/) See [ask advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice), please.

Comment: Can you give better details on the logic of how the data should be sorted and displayed? Can you give an example of a query you have tried so far so we have a starting point to understand better?

Comment: I need to show the latest data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use a subquery to select the `max(date)` for each `id` and then join that back to your table to get the result:

```
select t1.id,
  t1.date,
  t1.qty,
  t1.price
from yourtable t1
inner join
(
  select id, max(date) MaxDate
  from yourtable
  group by id
) t2
  on t1.id = t2.id
  and t1.date = t2.maxdate
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/08e0f/4).

Then if you want to `sum()` the result, you will use:

```
select t1.id,
  t1.date,
  sum(t1.qty *t1.price) Total
from yourtable t1
inner join
(
  select id, max(date) MaxDate
  from yourtable
  group by id
) t2
  on t1.id = t2.id
  and t1.date = t2.maxdate
group by t1.id, t1.date
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/08e0f/6)

Comment: wowww...... so the table in inner join can created from sub query too..... wooowwww..... i didn't think of it...